# Column 'CUSTOMERS.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying this simple query below but getting error. Please let me know what is wrong...

```
SELECT ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, SALARY
FROM CUSTOMERS 
GROUP BY age 
HAVING COUNT(age) >= 2;
```

Comment: You should always post the error you're getting + some information about the tables you're using, if you can provide some DML so people can execute it themselves, that'd be great as well.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for participating. You might want to consider adding more details to your question and adding example data. What is your expected result set? What are you trying to achieve? Without detailed information we will have a hard time answering your question. Add the missing information directly into your question by hitting the [edit] link.

Answer (score 2):

> Column 'CUSTOMERS.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is because you're selecting more columns from your query than you're using in your group by.
All columns in your SELECT clause have to either be in your group by, or be an aggregate.

So after knowing that, it depends on what result you want to achieve.

If you want to just fix that query you have to use:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, SALARY
FROM CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, SALARY 
HAVING COUNT(age) >= 2;
```

Comment: I don't think this is the exact query he needs, however he had an error, and I explained to him what he needs to know. If he doesn't specify what results he wants, we can only guess. Which is why I said " it depends on what result you want to achieve"

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY age` will "compact" a group of records with the same `age` value into one record. But each record in a group have its own `id` (and another fields) value - what value does you want to obtain in this single "compacted" record?

---

I think that you need

```sql
SELECT customers.*
FROM customers
JOIN ( SELECT age
       FROM customers 
       GROUP BY age 
       HAVING COUNT(age) >= 2 ) ages ON customers.age = ages.age
```